# FIWARE rules setting to connect remotly

Tags: ssh, cloud, fiware

I have watched a tutorial to launch a VM and connet to it remotly, but when I have to configure the rules to open SSH 22 I haven't succeed. Someone could help to configure correctly the paramenters. Thank so much in advance.

[This is the configuration I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MB99D.png)

Answer (score 0):

That's the way you should do. And the other thing you need to do is assigning a floating-ip your Virtual Machine.